# Why is my branch ahead of origin/master by too many commits?

Tags: git

In the project I'm working on right now I have just submitted a merge request that has been merged into master on origin (our gitlab server). After that I made a single commit to fix a typo, and manually merged my branch into master locally (please don't kill me).

I'm now puzzled by the message I get when I run `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 15 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Because as far as I understand my local master branch is only 3 commits ahead. This is the (slightly modified) output of `git log -n5`:

```
commit cdbbbfdaf55deef575914f2cbf8cfec549479973 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: bc1a6b9 a32002a
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 11:03:45 2023 +0100

    Merge into master

commit a32002a75a559943968d8694287dc16b1297e1cf (development-branch)
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 11:02:36 2023 +0100

    Fixed typo

commit bc1a6b9ba9b56063044730fb20cc5f1b43194dea (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 91f3302 eabfd24
Author: Developer 2
Date:   Wed Jan 4 09:33:41 2023 +0000

    Merge branch 'development-branch' into 'master'
    
    Development branch
    
    See merge request Repository!7

commit eabfd244f4791b66cf4c26a9fb574c9317279021
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 09:33:41 2023 +0000

    Development branch

commit 9eb2390feec6650a446bff4e9309bd29c7ed18e8 (origin/development-branch)
Merge: 2517a68 91f3302
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 10:26:37 2023 +0100

    Merge
```

A `git pull` says everything is up to date. Why this discrepancy?

---

### Edit

As @florieger points out, the output of `git log origin/master..master` shows 15 commits, the first three of which are:

```
commit cdbbbfdaf55deef575914f2cbf8cfec549479973 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: bc1a6b9 a32002a
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 11:03:45 2023 +0100

    Merge into master

commit a32002a75a559943968d8694287dc16b1297e1cf (development-branch)
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 11:02:36 2023 +0100

    Fixed typo

commit 9eb2390feec6650a446bff4e9309bd29c7ed18e8 (origin/development-branch)
Merge: 2517a68 91f3302
Author: Developer 1 (me)
Date:   Wed Jan 4 10:26:37 2023 +0100

    Merge

(12 additional commits not shown)
```

i.e. commits 1, 2 and 5 in `git log -n5`. But why is the merge (bc1a6) not visible here? The output of `git log -n5` seems to me to suggest that origin/master points to this ref, so why are they different?

Comment: "Merge branch .... into master" sounds like it merged several commits into master (possibly 12 commits?). `git pull` will not do anything if your local clone is _ahead_ (only if you are behind or diverged)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are on the master branch locally.
2. run `git log origin/master..master`

It should list you all 15 commits between origin/master and local master branch.

Comment: Ok, that does show 15 commits. But I don't understand why? I've updated the question.

Comment: @glaux. Maybe `development-branch` has a problem of root. For this branch the common ancestor commit with origin/master is older than you think. Maybe you have a forgotten `git pull` in your  `development-branch`. Try to restart. Perhaps my answer could help you there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237501/10489562